# Rvest ignore certain nested elements

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to learn how to scrape and practicing on yelp. I ran into a problem on one of the pages that has an extra nested div here:

https://www.yelp.com/biz/funny-bbq-new-york-2?start=40

I need to ignore the **Previous review**. I want to ignore it somehow. Here is the code i wrote to scrape everything else i need. I also want make sure it gets ignored on any page that has more than one, though i have not seen any. The problem with the **previous review** is the first three objects `dates`, `review_text` and `stars` are of length 11 but the last three only end up with 10

```
review_top <- "https://www.yelp.com/biz/funny-bbq-new-york-2?start=40" %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_elements("ul.undefined:nth-child(4)")

    reviews <- tibble(
        dates = review_top %>% html_elements(".margin-t1__09f24__w96jn") %>%
            html_text(),
        review_text = review_top %>% html_elements(".raw__09f24__T4Ezm") %>%
            html_text(),
        stars = review_top %>% html_elements(".i-stars__09f24__M1AR7") %>%
            html_attr("aria-label"),
        useful = review_top %>%
            html_elements(xpath = "(//span[@class=' css-12i50in'])[position() mod 3 = 1]") %>%
            html_text2(),
        funny = review_top %>%
            html_elements(xpath = "(//span[@class=' css-12i50in'])[position() mod 3 = 2]") %>%
            html_text2(),
        cool = review_top %>%
            html_elements(xpath = "(//span[@class=' css-12i50in'])[position() mod 3 = 0]") %>%
            html_text2()
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to approach this is to extract the 10 reviews on the page and then extract the desire information from each review.
Each review is a identified as
as `<div class = "review__09f24__oHr9V">` node underneath a
`<li class=margin-b5__09f24__pTvws div.review__09f24__oHr9V>` node.

The use of `html_element()` function no "s" will always provide 1 and one 1 result even if that result is NA.  This way we extracting information from 10 nodes and thus will return the first piece of information in each of the 10.  Any duplicates are ignored and missing values are returned as NA.

```
library(rvest)

page <- "https://www.yelp.com/biz/funny-bbq-new-york-2?start=40" %>%  read_html()

#Find all of the top level reviews
reviews <- page %>%  html_elements("li.margin-b5__09f24__pTvws div.review__09f24__oHr9V")

#extract the desired information from each review
dates <- reviews %>% html_element(".margin-t1__09f24__w96jn") %>% html_text()
review_text = reviews %>% html_element(".raw__09f24__T4Ezm") %>% html_text()
stars <- reviews %>% html_element("div.i-stars__09f24__M1AR7")%>% html_attr("aria-label")
useful = reviews %>%  html_element(xpath = "(//span[@class=' css-12i50in'])[position() mod 3 = 1]") %>%
   html_text2()

funny = reviews %>% html_elements(xpath = "(//span[@class=' css-12i50in'])[position() mod 3 = 2]") %>%
   html_text2()

cool = reviews %>% html_elements(xpath = "(//span[@class=' css-12i50in'])[position() mod 3 = 0]") %>%
   html_text2()

answer <- tibble(
   dates, review_text, stars,  useful,  funny, cool)
```

Comment: yeah for sure, a much easier way to do it. thank you! learned a lot from your comment